# Deploying MongoDB & Express based back-end API to Heroku dosen't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

I wrote a small front-end project with Vue.js, and Express was adopted in the back-end. The front-end and back-end were in two different directories respectively. The API works in my local environment but when I deploy my back-end api to Heroku, and tried GET request by Postman, it doesn't work.

In my `index.js`:

This is the listening port:
`const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;`

I am using mongoose to connect mLab:
`const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;`

`mongoose.connect(db)`

And my `package.json`is here:

```
{
    "name": "backend-api",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "server.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js",
        "server": "nodemon index.js"
    },
    "author": "Yeoman_Li",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
        "express": "^4.16.4",
        "mongoose": "^5.4.0"
    }
}
```

My `index.js` is here:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

// CORS
app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Content-type, Accept, X-Access-Token, X-Key"
    );
    if ("OPTIONS" == req.method) res.status(200).end();
    else next();
});

const mediaReq = require("./routes/api/mediaReq");

//  DB
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

// body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//  connect to DB
mongoose
    .connect(db)
    .then(() => console.log("MonogoDB Connected"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

//  router
app.use("/api/mediaReq", mediaReq);

// port
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

And here is my api router:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const mediaController = require("../../controllers/media");

//  test
router.get("/test", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ msg: "test works" });
});

// $route GET api/mediaReq/medias || /medias/:id
router.get("/medias", mediaController.allMedia);
router.get("/medias/:id", mediaController.byId);
router.post("/medias", mediaController.create);
router.delete("/medias/:id", mediaController.remove);

module.exports = router;
```

I used postman to send a simple GET request and it works:
`http://localhost:5000/api/mediaReq/medias`

But when I tried to send a GET request to my heroku backend-api, it doesn't work:
`https://fast-reaches-23458.herokuapp.com/api/mediaReq/medias`

Comment: Server should be listening on port 80 for your request

Comment: You mean I have to change my `index.js` like this: `const port = 80` or just change my request statement like this: `https://fast-reaches-23458.herokuapp.com:80/api/mediaReq/medias` ?

Comment: In index.js, your express server should listening to port 80, that's standard port for HTTP. I assume you'r not configure your virtual machine in different way, also try without https, just http